# Div background within while loop

Tags: php

when using (count/2) for giving background color in div, it applied for alternative boxes. But i want to give div background for first three boxes same color then for the next three boxes diff color then again for the next three boxes the first color then next three boxes the second color.

The alternative color should be applied for three boxes once. Please clarify this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use modulo

```
var c;
if (count % 6 < 3)
  // color one
  c = '#fff';
else
  // color two
  c = '#ccc';
```

Or as a one-liner

```
var c = count % 6 < 3 ? '#fff' : '#ccc';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
k=0, Color=Red

while()
{
    if(k == 3)
    {
      k=0;
     if(Color == Red) Color=Green
     else Color = Red

    }
    else
   {
     k++;
   }
}
```